# Error $ProfilePictureUrl is not replacing the pic id from My Database i.e Firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

I 'm developing Google Assistant in #js , I when user clicks my link http://host/$Profile , it needs to show profile pic but, $profile  is in my database, the $profile  should be replaced like  423466934206595086.jpg which is in my database. This is my code
"buttonUrl: 'http://armws.sste.saiveeetha.com/Content/ProfilePicture/$ProfilePictureUrl'   "----->when i click on that the url i.e $ProfilePictureUrl is not replacing the Pic Id................I don't know how to do that.........Please help me ....!!!

```
 const EmpId = agent.parameters.EmpId;
 var ref3 =  admin.database().ref().child("Table/");
var query3 = ref3.orderByChild("EmpId").equalTo(EmpId);
return query3.once("value",function(snapshot) {
 snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
 agent.add(`The Faculty name is  ` + child.val().FirstName);
agent.add(new Card({
  title: ` Name:${child.val().FirstName}
           Employee Id: ${child.val().EmpId}
           Address:: ${child.val().Address}  
           Email :  ${child.val().EmailId}
           DOB : ${child.val().DateOfBirth}
           Department: ${child.val().DepartmentName}`,
        imageUrl: 'https://eencrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR7lF8oXwLpXitlwizIdXVM-cGRTGqi79X3I4t5oBlNfhGe8mKN3Dg',
       text:  `Thanks for using Saveetha Google Assistant \n DR ${child.val().FirstName} `,
       buttonText: 'View Profile Picture',
      buttonUrl: 'http://........./Content/ProfilePicture/$ProfilePictureUrl'
```

Comment: check the `$ProfilePictureUrl` variable just before you use it for the button url and it would be good if you post a more complete script so we can get a whole picture view of your problem

Comment: Added please check sir

Comment: checkout my answer and accept if it worked out for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using JavaScript [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)! the wrong way.

in order for this `buttonUrl: 'http://........./Content/ProfilePicture/$ProfilePictureUrl'` to be parsed by js you need to rewrite it as

`` buttonUrl: `http://........./Content/ProfilePicture/${ProfilePictureUrl}` ``

this way JS will replace your variable `ProfilePictureUrl` with its value.

JS template literals must start with a backtick

`` var ProfilePictureUrl = 'World';
console.log(`Hello ${ProfilePictureUrl}`); ``

this will print out Hello World to the console